# Adjust margin when I click calendar on Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could you help me adjust the error below: as you can see when I click to choose a date, there is a part of the calendar "cut off", I would like to adjust this if I can. I will insert an executable code below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

Test <- structure(
  list(dat= c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03"),
       X= c(5,4,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 fileInput("file",h4(("Import file"),
                                           multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx")),
                                 uiOutput("date"),
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                   ),
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$df)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "database", 
              label = h4("Choose"),
              min = min(data()$df),
              max = max(data()$df),
              value = NA,
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O68jY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a couple of different things that will fix it.
Swapping the `fileInput` and `uiOutput` around fixes the problem.
Using `br()` in appropriate places can also fix this.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput("date"),
                                 fileInput("file",h4(("Import file"),
                                                     multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx")),
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                               ),
                             ))
  ))
```

or

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 fileInput("file",h4(("Import file"),
                                                     multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx")),
                                 uiOutput("date"),
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                               ),
                             ))
  ))
```